# Ansi C: High flow control/Replace just the first occurence with a *star* and delete each duplicate

Tags: c, arrays, replace, duplicates, control-flow

Here's another *brain teaser* i'm having issues with.

The question is pretty easy to understand:

> *A* is a **char array** of length **N**. Write a *replace(A)* function which will delete not only every **duplicate**, but also **replace**
>   just the *first* occurence with a *** (star).
>
> **i.e.:** `A[N]= A B C e A C f B`; After the *replace(A)* function is called, it'll change in: `A[N]= * * * e f`;

that's what i come up with so far, *didn't touch the deleting part yet, i'm still having troubles with changing the first occurence with star.*

```
#define N 8

void replace(char *A)
{
    int i=0,j=0,flag=0;

    while(i<N){
        flag=0;
        j=0;
        while(flag==0 && j<N){     
            if(A[i]!=A[j]){       //if the values are different
                flag=1;               //i quit the loop and the flag is
                // set to 'true'
            } 

            j++;                 //if i'm here the values are equal, i can keep going
            // till i reach the end or two different values.
        }   
        if(flag==1){           //if i quitted the loop -so the flag is 1-
            A[i]='*';             //i change the value in an *
        };

        i++;                //i can keep going. 
    }   
}
```

The output i'm having is: `********`. *i think it's because i'm comparing each letter with the same one.* How should it be constructed?

Comment: N.B No 'break' command allowed.

Comment: Each iteration processes the entire string. So you're always going to find chars that are not equal (`if(A[i]!=A[j]){`) so `flag` will always be set to `1`. Especially after the first time through when `A[0] = '*'`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm missing something important… Where is the condition specified, which should cause `A B C` to be replaced but `e f` left untouched?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Even if i set it to (if(A[i]==A[j]) it won't change the output.

Comment: What is YOUR question: are you asking how it happens that your code produces the output you get? Or are you asking how the code may/should be constructed to give a desired result?

Comment: @CiaPan i know why my code produces that output, i'm asking how it should be... you're right, sorry for missing on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is basically this.

1. Look at a letter.
2. Flag if any following letter is different.
3. If so, replace the original letter with a *

If we write your code with `for` loops the code is more clear. And if we add a few debugging prints we can see the problem.

```
void replace( char *A ) {
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        int flag = 0;
        printf("i = %d, A[i] = %c\n", i, A[i]);

        for(int j = 0; flag==0 && j<N; j++) {
            printf("    j = %d, A[j] = %c\n", j, A[j]);
            if( A[i]!=A[j] ) {
                flag=1;
            } 
        }

        if( flag==1 ) {
            A[i]='*';
        }
    }
}
```

Running this...

```
$ ./test
i = 0, A[i] = A
    j = 0, A[j] = A
    j = 1, A[j] = B
i = 1, A[i] = B
    j = 0, A[j] = *
i = 2, A[i] = C
    j = 0, A[j] = *
i = 3, A[i] = e
    j = 0, A[j] = *
i = 4, A[i] = A
    j = 0, A[j] = *
i = 5, A[i] = C
    j = 0, A[j] = *
i = 6, A[i] = f
    j = 0, A[j] = *
i = 7, A[i] = B
    j = 0, A[j] = *
********
```

The first problem is instead of looking at the following letters, you're always rescanning the whole string. The letter always sees itself.

The second is you're flagging for letters which are different, `A[i] != A[j]`. You're looking for duplicates to get letters which are the same, `A[i] == A[j]`. Unless all characters are unique there's always going to be a duplicate.

When we fix those two problems, start the inner loop at `j = i+` and flag if `A[i] == A[j]` we get a better result.

```
$ ./test
i = 0, A[i] = A
    j = 1, A[j] = B
    j = 2, A[j] = C
    j = 3, A[j] = e
    j = 4, A[j] = A
i = 1, A[i] = B
    j = 2, A[j] = C
    j = 3, A[j] = e
    j = 4, A[j] = A
    j = 5, A[j] = C
    j = 6, A[j] = f
    j = 7, A[j] = B
i = 2, A[i] = C
    j = 3, A[j] = e
    j = 4, A[j] = A
    j = 5, A[j] = C
i = 3, A[i] = e
    j = 4, A[j] = A
    j = 5, A[j] = C
    j = 6, A[j] = f
    j = 7, A[j] = B
i = 4, A[i] = A
    j = 5, A[j] = C
    j = 6, A[j] = f
    j = 7, A[j] = B
i = 5, A[i] = C
    j = 6, A[j] = f
    j = 7, A[j] = B
i = 6, A[i] = f
    j = 7, A[j] = B
i = 7, A[i] = B
***eACfB
```

This isn't going to work. Even if we rescanned the whole string each time, being careful to skip the current letter `A[i]`, the algorithm is destructive. The last A won't see the earlier As because they will have been turned into *.

There's a better way.

---

Loops in loops are generally bad news because they get very inefficient very fast. This is an O(N^2) solution meaning as the length of the string doubles it has to do 4 times the work.

Instead, we can do this in two passes. First, count the number of each character in a string. There's only 255 characters, so we can store this in just 255 bytes. (Note, if the string contains more than 255 duplicates of the same character this will overflow. To be really safe you'd just store 0, 1, or 2 representing unseen, unique, and duplicate. But for simplicity I'll just increment.)

```
unsigned short counts[255] = {0};
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    size_t this_char = (size_t)A[i];
    counts[this_char]++;
}
```

Then do a second pass in a second loop to do the transform based on the counts.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    size_t this_char = (size_t)A[i];
    if( counts[this_char] > 1 ) {
        A[i] = '*';
    }
}
```

This neatly separates the problem into two parts: count the characters, then deal with the more complicated replacement code. It simplifies the problem by splitting it up.

It's also more efficient. We only ever have to look through the string twice, O(2N) is much better than O(N^2). And we only use a small and fixed amount of stack memory.

But it isn't yet correct. It does the first part, replace duplicated letters with `*`, but not the second, only replace the first one.

```
***e**f*
```

---

Now it isn't a simple 1-to-1 replacement. We need to "slide" the following letters over. There's a number of ways to do this, we could allocate memory for a new string, build up that string, and copy it into the existing memory, but that's wasteful. There's a better way.

We can write in place. This will require keeping track of two positions in the string at the same time, where we're reading and where we're writing. This works because we're never writing more than we're reading, so the writer will always be at or behind the reader.

That is easy to mess up with indexes. It's easier to do this with pointers to track where we are in the string, so let's switch to pointers. This also means we don't need to know the size of the string anymore, we just increment the pointer until we hit a null byte.

```
void replace(char *A) {
    unsigned short counts[255] = {0};
    for( char *reader = A; *reader != '\0'; reader++ ) {
        size_t this_char = (size_t)*reader;
        counts[this_char]++;
    }

    for( char *reader = A; *reader != '\0'; reader++ ) {
        size_t this_char = (size_t)*reader;
        if( counts[this_char] > 1 ) {
            *reader = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

The next step is to separate our reading from writing. The first loop stays the same. To the second loop we'll add a `writer` pointer to track where in the string we're writing.

```
char *writer = A;
for( char *reader = A; *reader != '\0'; reader++ ) {
    size_t this_char = (size_t)*reader;
    if( counts[this_char] > 1 ) {
        *writer = '*';
        writer++;
    }
    else {
        *writer = *reader;
        writer++;
    }
}
```

Note that `writer` is only advanced when it's written to. In the above code its always written to, and normally you'd put `writer++` outside the if/else. But the next step changes that.

The next step is to track which letters have already been replaced and only replace the first time we see it. That means another tracking array. Just like `counts` we have `replaced`.

```
unsigned short replaced[255] = {0};
char *writer = A;
for( char *reader = A; *reader != '\0'; reader++ ) {
    size_t this_char = (size_t)*reader;

    // It's a duplicate and it hasn't been replaced yet
    if( counts[this_char] > 1 && !replaced[this_char] ) {
        // Replace it. Note that we replaced it. Advance the writer position.
        *writer = '*';
        replaced[this_char] = 1;
        writer++;
    }
    // It's unique.
    else if( counts[this_char] == 1 ) {
        // Write it. Advance the writer position.
        *writer = *reader;
        writer++;
    }
}
```

This gives us `***efCfB`, nearly there!

The final step is to truncate the string at wherever `writer` ends up after the reading is done, in this case it's pointing at `C`. You stop reading strings at a null byte, so after the loop is done we write a null byte.

```
*writer = '\0';
```

And we're there.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me, i really really appreciate it.

Comment: That's simple and clear. But it can be done in a single scan with only 256 bytes of temporary storage, and a guarantee of no overflow :-) Added bonus: the code is shorter.

Comment: @rici I figured there was a trick. I went with "most teachable" solution. Thanks for posting the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Brain teasers like this should always have a trick solution. And this one does.

The trick is the following: the output of this function must have no more than `UCHAR_MAX` characters. That's because there is only one output character for each *distinct* input character, and there are only `UCHAR_MAX` possible distinct characters. Furthermore, one of those values represents `NUL`, and since no character inside the string can be `NUL`, we can say that the maximum *string length* of the output must be less than `UCHAR_MAX` characters.

Finally, the output cannot be longer than the input, so it is possible to use the input array as the output. That might not be useful in general, but we'll make use of it here to avoid having to return a different array.

Now, let's imagine scanning over the input string, more or less in the manner suggested by @Schwern in this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805945/1566221). Leaving aside the mechanics of how we actually make the decision, we can say that there are only two possible actions for each character:

1. If we've never seen this character before, we add it to the output
2. If we've seen this character before, we change the instance of it we already added to the output to a `*`.

In order to be able to do both of those things, we need to keep track of

1. Whether we've seen this character before, and
2. If we've seen it before, where we put it.

The obvious way to do that would be to keep an array of `UCHAR_MAX` pointers into the output array, one for every possible distinct character. Initially, these pointers would all be NULL, indicating that we've never seen the character before. When we first see the character and add it to the output array, we set the corresponding pointer to the current output position; that will later not only indicate that we've seen the character before, but also tell us where to put the star.

That would require an array of `UCHAR_MAX` pointers, which would normally be 2k bytes on a 64-bit machine. But, as you might have figure out by now, there are only `UCHAR_MAX` possible distinct pointer values, so we really only need a single byte for each distinct character. There are two obvious ways to do this mapping; in the following code, I use the actual offset in the output array for every character which is in the output array, and `UCHAR_MAX` (which cannot be a possible offset of an output character) for characters which haven't yet been seen. (The other obvious solution is to increment everything by 1, allowing the use of zero as the "never been seen" marker.)

So:

```
int replace(char* A) {
  unsigned char offset[UCHAR_MAX];
  memset(offset, UCHAR_MAX, UCHAR_MAX); /* Set all offsets to UCHAR_MAX */
  int out = 0;     /* The position to add the next distinct character */
  char* scan;      /* The next character to read */
  for (scan = A; *scan; ++scan) {  /* For each input character */
    unsigned char ch = *scan;  /* chars might be negative; offsets must be positive */
    if (offset[ch] == UCHAR_MAX) {
      /* Never seen this character before */
      offset[ch] = out;       /* Record where it is */
      A[out++] = *scan;       /* Put it there and up the count */
    }
    else {
      /* We've already seen this character */
      A[offset[ch]] = '*';   /* Overwrite it with a star */
    }
  }
  /* NUL-terminate the output and return its length */
  A[out] = 0;
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking for design hints,

*and*

assuming the first occurence of any character should be replaced with a star **only if** some duplicates of the character exist somewhere else in the array;

I'd propose to describe the desired behavior this way:

```
for each character in the array
    test if a duplicate exists in the rest of the array;
    if so,
        remove all duplicates
        and replace the first occurence with '*'
```

It's not clear, however, what it means 'to remove duplicates'. If we consider the input to be a *string*, i.e. a (potentially) variable-length, NUL-terminated chain of characters, then removing a character from the string is equivalent to copying the string's tail over preceding places along with the terminating NUL byte. OTOH if we're told the input is an *array*, i.e. a structure of *fixed* length, we can remove characters by replacing them e.g. with spaces, or by copying towards the array beginning and overwriting the released tail positions with a space. We can also keep a value of an 'actual' length of the array and decrement it on character 'removal'. Then wewould haveto return both a modified array and its new 'actual length' as a result.

Alas, your description of the problem is not consistent with any of the above interpretations.
First, you use a notation `A[N]`, which denotes an `N`-th item (counting from zero!) of the array `A` in C language, **not** an `N`-item array.
Second, you present 'the same' `A[N]` which has different lengths (8 characters before modification and 5 characters after it).
Additionally, you present the strings with spaces between letters – it's not quite clear if they're actual part of data (and how should they be handled?) or just a presentation trick.
Third, you don't show a C-like delimiters of strings, which suggests it is a plain char array, not a string...
And fourth, you don't define an actual way of handling a 'shrinking length' of the array.

In the following code I assume the length of the array is passed explicitly as a parameter to a function, and the function returns a new size of reduced data.

```
int replace(char *A, int N)
{
    int first, next; // positions of 1st & any next occurence
    for(first = 0; first < N; ++first)
    {
        for(next = first+1; next < N; ++next) // seek a duplicate
        {
            if(A[next] == A[first]) // found?
            {
                int del = next;    // position to be removed
                while(++next < N)  // scan the rest of A[]
                {
                    if(A[next] != A[first]) // not a duplic.
                        A[del++] = A[next]; // retain it
                }
                N = del;        // a new size
                A[first] = '*'; // replace the 1st occurence
            }
        }
    }
    return N;
}
```